# $_POST in php not returning any data

Tags: php, post

I have written the following php called `fetchdetails.php`

```
<?php
$db ="fb"; 
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","paswd") or die ("hi ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("helo".mysql_error());

$id = $_POST["id"];
echo $id;
$id = (string)$id;
echo $id."hi";
```

when i am calling it using `www.anyaddress.com/fetchdetails.php?id=1722315` but echo $id is not showing anything. Need help on this asap. Actually i did this the same thing earlier in some other code and it was working fine.

Comment: That's a `$_GET`, not a `$_POST`.  echo `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If want to get the values from a URL query such as the `id` part from

> `http://example.com?id=42`

You should **always** use the **`$_GET`** super-global array as in:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id; // 42
```

On the otherhand, you should use **`$_POST`** to get any data submitted via an HTML form. 
 You use `$_POST["id"];` only when you want to get queries submitted via a form

Whatever the case maybe, you should not trust any data passed by either POST/GET. Therefore, before you put it in you mysql query, you should sanitize/escape it.

Like this:  `$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']),`

*Note.* Every function that starts with `mysql_` is depredicated is unsafe to use, so you must learn about PDO or MySQLi

Comment: @Eritrea: To make sure there's time for enough opinions to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this lines

```
$db ="fb"; 

$con = mysql_connect("host","user","paswd") or die ("hi ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db) or die("helo".mysql_error());
```

and check does it work then. If does then you have problem while establishing connection.

If not check are you sending **POST** or **GET** request and is it **sent**.

Comment: How would that effect `echo $id;`'s lack of output? That part doesn't even use `$id`.

Comment: Didn't read whole comment or he edited it. Thought it didn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `$_REQUEST` variable, if value can be from any of the following
`$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE`